# error while launching qweb report from python

Tags: python-3.5, odoo-11

I'm upgrading a module from odoo v10 to odoo v11. It is founded that the get_action is replaced with report_action.
so I used the code as follows
 `self.env.ref('report_action_name').report_action(self, data=data, config=False)`

but it gives me error 
AttributeError: 'ir.ui.view' object has no attribute 'report_action'
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more information, such as the context of the code

Comment: Can you provide `report_action_name` definition ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that `report_action_name` is the `record_id` of the report . 
Eg:

> Python

```
self.env.ref('module_name.record_id').report_action(self, data=data, config=False)
```

> xml

```
 <record id="record_id" model="ir.actions.report">
        <field name="name">Name</field>
        <field name="model">Model</field>
        <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
        <field name="report_name">module_name.report_template_id</field>
    </record>
```

> Report XML

```
<template id="report_template_id">
  <Your code>
</template>
```