# ODOO 11 report, object has no attribute 'report_action'

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

Good day to all.
Trying to make custom ODOO 11 report to save it to pdf.
Report template(w/out any values, just for test purposes)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="contract_template">
            <t t-call="web.html_container">
                <div class="article">
                    <h2>Report title</h2>
                    <p>Report 01</p>
                </div>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

If I call this template from XML like this:

```
<report
   id="custom_template_1"
   model="res.partner.contract.wizard"
   string="Contract"
   report_type="qweb-pdf"
   name="client_contracts.contract_template"
   file="client_contracts.contract_template"
   menu="False"
/>
```

And add button to view it works fine - it generate report.
But when I'm trying to generate this report with python code:

```
    def get_pdf_contract(self):
        context = self._generate_context()
        return self.env.ref('client_contracts.contract_template').report_action(self, data=context)
```

And add button to view:

```
<button string="Test pdf x" type="object" name="get_pdf_contract" />
```

When I press this button there is an error:

```
AttributeError: 'ir.ui.view' object has no attribute 'report_action'
```

Anyone can give me helping hand with that? Thanx for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution.
For anyone, who get same error/trouble - solution.
Just skip the

```
return self.env.ref('client_contracts.contract_template').report_action(self, data=context)
```

part, and replace it with

```
return {'type': 'ir.actions.report','report_name': 'client_contracts.contract_template','report_type':"qweb-pdf",'data': context,}
```

where context - previously generated dict of values, that need to be passed to template.
client_contract - name of module, conrtact_template - name of template

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
return self.env.ref('client_contracts.contract_template').report_action(self, data=context)
```

with

```
return self.env.ref('client_contracts.custom_template_1').report_action(self, data=context)
```

means

```
return self.env.ref('module.report id').report_action(self,data=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this stack overflow question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906043/error-while-launching-qweb-report-from-python), works fine.

To note: the `report_id` referenced below should refer to the report where you have declared name of report and type and file ... and not the `template_id`.

`return self.env.ref('module_name.report_id').report_action(self, data=context)`