# AttributeError: 'ir.ui.menu' object has no attribute 'report_action' when generating report through action wizard

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

Sooo, I try to generate report with action wizard, but I always get "AttributeError: 'ir.ui.menu' object has no attribute 'report_action'" error, this only happen when I try generating report trough a wizard, when I use the print button, it's always working, I already tried following [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119228/odoo-11-report-object-has-no-attribute-report-action) post, and [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906043/error-while-launching-qweb-report-from-python) but nothing, I still get the error.

Here's the snippet of my code :
Module name : hotel_promo
Python code

```
from odoo import models, fields

class hotelreport(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'hotel.report.wizard'

    employee = fields.Many2one('res.users', string="Employee")
    from_date = fields.Date(string="Starting Date")
    to_date = fields.Date(string="Ending Date")

    def action_print_report(self):
        data = {
            'start_date': self.from_date,
            'end_date': self.to_date,
            'employee': self.employee.id
        }
        return self.env.ref('hotel_promo.print_report').report_action(self, data=data)
```

report.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
        <record id="print_report" model="ir.actions.report">
                <field name="name">Hotel Report</field>
                <field name="model">hotel.report.wizard</field>
                <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
                <field name="report_name">hotel_promo.report_hotel</field>
                <field name="report_file">hotel_promo.report_hotel</field>
                <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_hotel_report"/>
                <field name="binding_type">report</field>
        </record>
</odoo>
```

Report Template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="report_hotel">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <div class="page">
                        <div style="padding-bottom:50px !important;" class="oe_structure"/>
                        <h2 align="center">Hotel Report</h2>
                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Month</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

Wizard form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="print_hotel_report" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Hotel Report</field>
            <field name="model">hotel.report.wizard</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
               <form>
                   <group>
                       <group string="Select Employee">
                           <field name="employee"/>
                       </group>
                       <group string="Select Date">
                           <field name="from_date"/>
                           <field name="to_date"/>
                       </group>
                       <footer>
                           <button string="Print Report" name="action_print_report" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
                           <button string="Discard" class="btn-default" special="cancel"/>
                       </footer>
                    </group>
               </form>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: most probably same id being used twice, once in menu record, another with tgis report record. just change the report id to something unique like and `print_report_1` change to `return self.env.ref('hotel_promo.print_report_1').report_action(self, data=data)`

Comment: yeah, thank you, I am really stupid for making this mistake and not realizing it, after I see your comment, I immediately check my menu xml, and there it stood, my menu to open wizard with an ID of print_report.... I should have name it report_wizard or something...